# $3x + 1 = 2^i$ only has integer solutions when $i$ is even

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I came across this question while looking at powers of 2 and investigating number theory. I found it quite interesting, unfortunately I would say that my skills in number theory are far too primitive to solve this. My question is, is this true?
$$i \in \mathbb{N} \land \exists j \in \mathbb{N}, 2j = i \implies \exists x \in \mathbb{N}, 3x + 1 = 2^i$$

> $\frac{2^i - 1}{3}$ is an integer only when $i$ is even

I think it has something to due with the fact that $2^1 = 2$ is 1 away from $3$ and $2^2 = 4$ is $1$ away from 3 but in the other direction. I know this has to do with modular arithmetic (or at least I'm guessing) and the fact that I guess when you subtract $2^i$ by $1$ and $i$ is even, then you bring it down one mod cycle to become divisible by $3$, and then multiplying $2^i$ by $4$ doesn't affect the mod cycle of $2^i - 1$ against $3$ (i.e. its divisibility by $3$)

Comment: Can we all agree that whoever chose $i$ as a variable clearly wasn't thinking ahead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be divisible by $3$, you want it to equal $0 \mod 3$.
$$2^i - 1 \equiv 0 \mod 3$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (-1)^i \equiv 1 \mod 3$$

Replacing the $2$ with a $-1$ might make it clearer.

And certainly the last equality holds if and only if $i$ is even. As you were trying to do, it is also possible to look at the cycle of taking $2^i$ for various $i$ and finding out how long it takes to loop around.